# How to handle sprites when moving out of the camera view?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity2D and trying to teach myself based on making clones of older games and my first one is Spacewar (1962 game).

The problem I cannot wrap my head around is setting up a script (I think this is the correct approach) for when my sprite goes off camera on one edge it will appear on the opposite edge, example if you are not familiar with Spacewar would be PacMan when PacMan goes off the screen and appears on the opposite side.

How should I approach this because there are other games in the list of my cloning projects that will also share this same view mechanic.

I feel like I have the logic inside my head perfectly on what needs to be done but at the same time I am so new to Unity that syntax is preventing me from moving forward.

Should this be based on :
1) Having collision on my edges and just moving it to the opposite side
or
2) Go based on camera edges.

I kinda think it might be something along the lines of #2 because what if the screen size is different on another computer.

Comment: In case you don't get an answer: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was this "Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, 6.0, -6.0)".  This solved my problem from going off the screen on one edge and reappearing in the other.  This is just for the left and right edges.

```
if(transform.position.x < -6.0 || transform.position.x > 6.0){
    var xPos : float = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, 6.0, -6.0);
    transform.position = Vector2(xPos, transform.position.y);
}
```